# Can I call a group of simulations "simulations with parameter A"?

Tags: expressions

I have an algorithm, and the performance of the algorithm will be influenced by several parameters. If I carry a group of simulations to test the algorithm's performance against parameter A, is it correct to say that the group of simulations is "simulations with parameter A"? Or some other proposition is more suitable than "with"? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I think a more clear phrase would be</strike>

> Simulations based on parameter A

or if parameter A has a shorter name (preferably one word like A):

> A-based simulations

### Edit

According to your comment I think these phrases (or any other combination of these words) would be more clear:

> Simulations with changing of parameter A
>
> Simulations based on altering of parameter A
>
> Simulations regarding modifying of parameter A

I personally prefer

> Simulations based on altering of parameter A

Comment: Thank you. But that sounds a little wired as the group of simulations is not based on the parameter A but just  simulations when A is tuned.

Comment: Then you need to pinpoint the changing nature of parameter. Take a look at my edited post

Comment: "Simulations with changing of parameter A" would be a good choice to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean you have e.g. parameters A, B and C and in this simulation group you are testing the performance with varying values of A, with B and C being invariant. This seems quite technical so there may be a standard way of saying this.

Incidentally, I wasn't sure what you intended by carry other than "have".

Comment: In fact I conduct a series of simulations.(I don't know if I use the right verb). I want to know if "simulations with parameter A" could express the meaning that "this group of simulations is conducted in the way that changing the values of A while keeping the values of B and C invariant".